# Angular directive update view on different events (Character Counter)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a characterCounter attribute directive for input fields. My thoughts are to require: 'ngModel' to get the length of the modelValue in ng-model and to pass a max-length in the scope of the directive.

```
<input ng-model="inputModel" max-character-counter max-length="10"/>
```

I have my directive most of the way there I'm just struggling with how I get the view to update. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
angular.module('app').directive('maxCharacterCounter', [function(){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '?ngModel',
  scope: {
    maxLength: "="
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (!ngModel) return;

    console.log(ngModel);

    ngModel.$render = function() {
      console.log('render');
      var el = angular.element(attrs.$$element);
      el.after('<span class="input-group-addon">' + scope.charactersLeft + '</span>');
    }

    elem.on('blur keyup change', function() {
      scope.$evalAsync(read);
    });
    read();

    function read() {
      scope.charactersLeft = ngModel.$modelValue.length == undefined ? scope.maxLength : scope.maxLength - ngModel.$modelValue.length;
      console.log('Characters Left:', scope.charactersLeft);
      console.log('View Value: ', ngModel.$viewValue);
      console.log('Model Value: ', ngModel.$modelValue);
      updateViewValue();
    }

    function updateViewValue() {
      //How do I update the view for scope.charactersLeft
      //ngModel.$viewValue(scope.charactersLeft);
      console.log('scope: ', scope);
    }
  }
}}]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/F0PzE6?p=preview

Final Solution:

```
angular.module('app').directive('maxCharacterCounter', ['$timeout', '$log', function($timeout, $log) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: '?ngModel',
  scope: {
    maxLength: "@"
  },
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (!ngModel) {
      $log.warn('ngModel doesn\'t exist. There is no way to calculate characters left');
      return;
    }

    elem.wrap('<div class="input-group"></div>');
    elem.after('<span class="input-group-addon"></span>');

    elem.on('blur keyup keydown change', function() {
      scope.$eval(updateCharacterCount);
      updateViewValue();
    });

    $timeout(function(){
      scope.maxLength = scope.maxLength || 140;
      scope.$eval(updateCharacterCount);
      updateViewValue(); 
    });

    function updateCharacterCount() {
      scope.charactersLeft = !ngModel.$viewValue ? scope.maxLength : scope.maxLength - ngModel.$viewValue.length;
    }

    function updateViewValue() {
      var element = elem.next('span');
      element.text(scope.charactersLeft);
      element.toggleClass('redText', scope.charactersLeft <= 0 ? true : false);
    }
  }
}}]);
```

Comment: check my answer on example for template usage. if you face some other issue. let me know

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/F0PzE6?p=preview is not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. add the second parameter of module.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
 .directive('maxCharacterCounter', function() {
   return {

     restrict: 'A',

     require: '?ngModel',

     scope: {
       maxLength: "="
     },

     link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
       if (!ngModel) return;

       ngModel.$render = function() {
         console.log('render');
         var el = angular.element(attrs.$$element);
         el.after('<span ng-bind="charactersLeft" class="input-group-addon">' + scope.charactersLeft + '</span>');
       }

       elem.on('blur keyup change', function() {
         scope.$evalAsync(read);
       });
       read();

       function read() {
         scope.charactersLeft = ngModel.$modelValue.length == undefined ? scope.maxLength : scope.maxLength - ngModel.$modelValue.length;
         updateViewValue();
       }

       function updateViewValue() {
         angular.element(attrs.$$element).next('span').text(scope.charactersLeft);
       }
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app"> 
  <input ng-model="inputModel" max-character-counter max-length="10"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this actually helps me. I'm trying to add a template after the <input/> my directive is an attribute of. I don't wan't to build an element directive that contains the input as well. var el = angular.element(attrs.$$element);
          el.after(//apply template);

Comment: i got your point here. let me know your current issue in the question. please revisit update it

Comment: Updated the answer. check now

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can literally bind to the length of your input model, like so:

```
{{inputModel.length}}
```

Unless I'm missing something, isnt this all you need?

Comment: This is a little different problem then what your thinking. I'm already using .length in my directive to calculate characters left. My issue is that I'm pushing a template onto the dom using .after(). As you type I need a way to update what is displayed on the dom. Venkatraman gave me what I was looking for.